# Strong monotone limits and dense subalgebras of von Neumann algebras, again

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

**Edit:** I just realized that this question is related to Andreas Thom's very interesting question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34692/subalgebras-of-von-neumann-algeb). I think the question below is more crude...

Michael's question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103240/dense-subalgebras-of-von-neumann-algebras-and-increasing-nets) reminded me of [the first lemma of this paper of Kadison](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/1969954.pdf), establishing that those $C^{*}$-algebras $\mathcal{A}\subset B(\mathcal{H})$ for which the set of self-adjoint elements $\mathcal{A_{s.a.}}$ is strong-operator closed under taking monotone increasing limits are, in fact, von Neumann algebras. I've often wondered about the following

> **Question:** What are necessary and sufficient conditions on a $*$-subalgebra $\mathcal{A}\subset B(\mathcal{H})$ such that strong operator closure of $\mathcal{A_{s.a.}}$ under monotone increasing nets guarantees that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed in the strong operator topology (i.e. is actually a von Neumann algebra)?

I'd like to know if there are weaker conditions than $\mathcal{A}$ being a $C^{\ast}$-algebra for which Kadison's conclusion holds. For example, conditions including things like "$\mathcal{A}$ is closed under continuous functional calculus" and such, which are essentially equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$ being a $C^{*}$-algebra in the (singly-generated) abelian case, but not in general.

(My impression is that this question is really tough, but I hope I'm wrong. It would be nice even to have an expert's digression on precisely *why* this question should be tough...as I'd learn some new things from that insight!)

It is also possible to ask about analogues of Pedersen's "up-down" theorem, which says that any self-adjoint element in the strong closure of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is the strong limit of a monotone decreasing sequence of self-adjoint elements each of which is a strong limit of a monotone increasing sequence of self-adjoint elements. Can one weaken the $C^{\ast}$-condition on $\mathcal{A}$ and still get this result? (I've tried to modify the argument in Pedersen's $C^{*}$-*algebras and their automorphism groups* but if I remember correctly this seems to use the *definition of a* $C^{*}$-algebra in an essential way. Is there a way around this?!)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer. Recently, I have been thinking questions related to yours, and I posted some of them on the [board](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103860/the-monotone-closure-of-a-c-algebra), so you may have seen them. I also posted related references in my comments there, but I think that you have already read those papers. It’s possible to ask a more general question: “Which subsets $S\subset\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})_{sa}$ have the property $S^m=S_m=S$?” or “Which real linear subspaces $S\subset\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})_{sa}$ have the property $S^m=S$?”  It would be interesting if these simple conditions implied $S$ being strongly closed.

Comment: No in both cases. Again, check the commutative case first!

Comment: (In both cases, you can find a counterexample where $S$ contains no comparable elements, hence $S = S^m = S_m$ trivially.)